# Angular UI Datepicker

Tags: angularjs, uidatepicker

I know how to use date-disabled as an attribute. But I couldn't make it work with global config. I have tried something like below. But, it doesn't work.
Could anyone here show me how to make it work.

Many thanks for your helps,

Huy

```
moduleB.config(function (datepickerConfig, datepickerPopupConfig) {
datepickerConfig.dateDisabled = function(date, mode) {
    return (mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6));
};
```

}

Comment: Try changing `(date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6)` to `((date.getDay() === 0) || (date.getDay() === 6))`.

Comment: Thanks Ross. But it still doesn't work.